# C# - Code to set build action of newly created xml file

Tags: c#, xml, file

I have code that creates a new Xml file and then I simply save it to a location in another project. My question is, is there code that I can write so that:

1. My file gets included in my project.
2. Build Action gets set to Content.
3. Set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Output files are not part of a project.  When you publish application you may want to add the output file as a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...
You may find better approaches possibly, but this one isn't bad (for me) and should work.

The settings outlined in the question are typically entries in the project file (.csproj). Try editing the .csproj file on the target location and add the entries.

You will have to first search for a tag in csproj XML file, with tag name `<ItemGroup>` that has child tag(s) with name `<Content>`. If you do not find any, add an `<ItemGroup>` when you write your xml entries to the proj file. If you find one, just add the  tage part in the below string to that ItemGroup tag.

```
@"<ItemGroup>" + // Add this parent node only if you do not find an existing one as mentioned above
"<Content Include="MyXmlFileNameWithExtemsionAndPath.xml">" +
"<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory></Content>" +
"</ItemGroup>" // Add this only if you do not find an existing one as mentioned above
```

Comment: Can I do this by making it a XDocument and going through the elements down to it and adding it that way? What would be the best approach to searching tags and adding?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way to do. Load the csproj into the XDocument and do the changes.

Comment: That worked. So now my question is: Is there a way to keep from the window box popping up to reload? Is there a way to code that so that it reloads automatically?

Comment: That is an IDE feature, so you can update the Visual Studio preferences to have them auto-reloaded. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741194/755133)

Comment: I checked that and when I follow those instructions, it continues to come up.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I read the below somewhere, worth a try.

For VS2008: Tools > Options > Documents > Detect when a file is changed outside the environment

For VS2010/2012/2013/2015: Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Detect when a file is changed outside the environment

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139752/vs2008-disable-asking-whether-to-reload-files-changed-outside-the-ide)

Comment: I am using 2019 and it is under Tools > Options > Documents > ...